# Hooking up a Kinect?

Tags: peripherals, driver

There is a driver project established to run Kinect on Linux. See here: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect

Will this work with an RPi? What are the constraints/obstacles likely to be?

I'm thinking this would be a real help for an ambitious robotics project, eg, setup an RPi as an onboard controller, with the Kinect as the "eyes" for object avoidance etc (or more).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have just installed this library successfully in Arch Linux. I can't see any reason why it wouldn't install in any distro. 
It's important to note that I **do not have a Kinect**, so I cannot verify that the library works, only that it compiles and installs successfully.

Here are the steps I took:

### Install dependencies

These packages are dependencies of the Kinect Library or the build process, and thus need installing first:

- `cmake`
- `git`
- `libusb`
- `freeglut`
- `libxmu`
- `libxi`

You should be able to find these using your basic package manager.

### Check out the repository

```
git clone git://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect.git
cd libfreenect && git pull origin
```

### Build the source

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DPROJECT_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/include -DLIB_SUFFIX="" .
make
sudo make install
```

Set the udev rules (so that the Kinect is detected when plugged in):

```
sudo install -Dm644 platform/linux/udev/51-kinect.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/51-kinect.rules
```

Comment: Do you reckon the RPi has the grunt to process the output from a Kinect any meaningful way?

Comment: @JonEgerton: I would suggest it would not. But this you can only find out by experimentation.

Comment: Kudos for compiling drivers whilst not having a device.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible...[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UM2uOIqgu8w)

I doubt it will be very practical to see anything, but if you just used data collection/processing, it might work. Side note: the Kinect eats up a HUGE amount of RAM to run all the visual stuff. So you could run a pared back version. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Kinect works on Pi after some tweaks. Here is an **[example](http://jonmacey.blogspot.com/2012/07/raspberry-pi-and-kinect.html)**.

Comment: No it doesn't work ... read the entire example: "Jon Macey 13 November 2012 01:31, As far as I know nobody has had any luck with video or depth, I'm considering getting the new 512M version of the pi and giving it another go but think it is unlikely y to work as the bottleneck seems to be in the USB drivers".